# How can I use grep or any other utility to get a string from a structured data based on a condition?

Tags: bash, unix

```
Name                 State           Dns
DeltaService         running         DeltaService.test.qa.domain.com
DeltaService_1       stopped   
DeltaService_2       stopped         DeltaService_2.test.qa.domain.com
UnitedService        running         UnitedService.test.qa.domain.com
UnitedService_1      stopped         
UnitedService_2      running         UnitedService_2.test.qa.domain.com
```

The above data shows as part of my logs during execution.
What I want to do is to search the logs for services with a similar name that have a DNS and store them in an array using bash script. For example if I want DeltaService, I want to be able to retrieve **"DeltaService"** and **"DeltaService_2"** and store in an array where I can use those service names for further processing. How can I achieve this?
What I have tried:

```
#"${serviceLogs[@]}" = contains the structured data.

print -- '%s\n' "${serviceLogs[@]}" | grep -oh "\w*DeltaService\w*"

output:
DeltaService
DeltaService_1
DeltaService_2

#I don't need DeltaService_1 because it has no DNS.
```

Comment: how is`${serviceLogs[@]}` initially populated? do you use this array anywhere else in your script? wondering if it might be easier to extract the desired data from the original source; when I run your code against that output I get 5 lines of output (not the 3 lines of output shown in the question) ... can you update the question with the output from `typeset -p serviceLogs`?

Comment: do you just need to dump the results to stdout or do you need to save the results? if you need to save the results ... in what format? to a file? to a variable? into an array?

Comment: @markp-fuso I need to save the results to an array. Then I can use a for loop to work with the service names in that array. To your first question, the data is generated by running a command. For example: serviceLogs=@( systemctl list-units --type=service ) is how the data is populated. Then I echo "${serviceLogs}" to see the data. # systemctl list-units --type=service is just an example.

Comment: in that case `serviceLogs` is not an array but rather a variable containing multiline text (ie, a long string with embedded linefeeds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` seems to be the right tool for that:

```sh
printf -- '%s\n' "${serviceLogs[@]}" |
awk '$1 ~ /^DeltaService/ && $3 != "" {print $1}'
```

```
DeltaService
DeltaService_2
```

Answer (score 2):

Per OP's comments:

```
serviceLogs='Name                 State           Dns
DeltaService         running         DeltaService.test.qa.domain.com
DeltaService_1       stopped   
DeltaService_2       stopped         DeltaService_2.test.qa.domain.com
UnitedService        running         UnitedService.test.qa.domain.com
UnitedService_1      stopped         
UnitedService_2      running         UnitedService_2.test.qa.domain.com'
```

One idea using `awk` to parse the data:

```
$ awk -v ptn="DeltaService" '$1~ptn && $3 {print $1}' <<< "${serviceLogs}"
DeltaService
DeltaService_2
```

Storing the results in a `bash` array named `services[]`:

```
$ services=( $(awk -v ptn="DeltaService" '$1~ptn && $3 {print $1}' <<< "${serviceLogs}") )
$ typeset -p services
declare -a services=([0]="DeltaService" [1]="DeltaService_2")
```